# Populate a listbox using mySQL and PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to populate a listbox with the results of a MySQL query. This is what I have tried:

```
 <select>
 <?php
 $type = "processors";
 $stmt2 = mysqli_prepare($link, "SELECT id, name, price FROM products WHERE type=?");
 $stmt2->bind_param("s", $type);
 $stmt2->execute();
 echo "<select class name='productlist'>";
 $stmt2->bind_result($products_id, $products_name, $products_price);
 while($stmt2->fetch()){
 echo "<option value='".$row[$products_id]."'>".$row[$products_name]."</option>";
 }
 $stmt2->close();
 ?>
 </select>
```

I have an error with this line:

```
echo "<option value='".$row[$products_id]."'>".$row[$products_name]."</option>";
```

Error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: row

This should load the data into the listbox; however, no data is populated as I have this above error. How can I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: You never assign the results of your query to a variable named `$row`. They are assigned to `$products_id`, `$products_name`, and `$products_price` respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You bind the results of your query to scalar variables, so now all you have to do is use them. You have no `$row` in your code.

```
$stmt2->bind_result($products_id, $products_name, $products_price);
while($stmt2->fetch()){
    echo "<option value='$products_id'>$products_name</option>";
}
$stmt2->close();
?>
```